# Why does shape return the size (xxxx, ) for my pandas dataframe and not (xxxx, 1)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using train_test_split with my dataframe, my code looks something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
y = df[0]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y,test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

When I print y.shape or y_train.shape it's returning (2871,). When I print y or y_train it returns what I would expect, a list of all the y values in my file so why is the shape not (2871, 1)?

Answer (score 0):

That's just how numpy prints out 1-dimensional arrays. Pandas uses numpy under the hood for dataframes, so you get that shape. Once you go to 2-dimensional and higher, you'll start seeing more values in the shape tuple. [Some examples from numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. I realized my issue was I made a numpy array with the code array = np.zeros((1, 58)) which was my issue. Although this leads me to the question, why is it if I transpose that array it has the shape (58, 1) but my y dataframe has the shape (2871, ). Shouldn't the numpy zero array have the shape (58, ) ?

Comment: I believe that is because the first array is actually a 2D array in memory. Although the transposition logically makes it 1D, it is still a 2D object. The link this was marked duplicate as has an interesting discussion with visuals of how the 1D case is treated. Without looking at the code, I assume most numpy functions operate with 1D as a special case, and nD as a general case.